# Backup for ubuntu 12.04 NOT Deja Dup

Tags: software-recommendation, backup, ftp

I am interested in a backup solution (alternative to Deja Dup, as I do not like its characteristics) My requirements:

- R-SYNC or Differential
- Backup to FTP server
- Store files as-is (if file name is a.txt, store as a.txt, not compressed or encrypted)

  Previous file support is NOT required.

For Ubuntu 12.04 desktop. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try Lucky Backup

> Lucky Backup is an application that backs-up and/or synchronizes any
>   directories with the power of rsync, another simple backup tool.
>   Features include backup, safety, synchronization, exclude/only include
>   options, allows custom rsync options, remote connections, restore and
>   dry-run operations, scheduling, profiles and command line mode.<sup>1</sup>

To install it you can either [download](http://luckybackup.sourceforge.net/download.html) it, or install it from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Another one is Grsync

> Grsync is a simple Rsync graphical user interface(GUI) using GTK2,
>   while Rsync is a powerful open source command line backup tool for
>   Linux.<sup>2</sup>

To install it you can [download](http://www.opbyte.it/grsync/download.html) it from Grsync

Another Solution is AMANDA.

> AMANDA, the Advanced Maryland Automatic Network Disk Archiver, is a
>   backup solution that allows the IT administrator to set up a single
>   master backup server to back up multiple hosts over network to tape
>   drives/changers or disks or optical media.<sup>3</sup>

To install it you can [download](http://www.amanda.org/download.php) it fro Amanda

For a list of other backup software click [Here](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20090105114152803/Backup.html)

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[luckybackup](http://luckybackup.sourceforge.net/)</sup>

<sup><sup>**2**</sup>Source:[Grsync](http://www.opbyte.it/grsync/)</sup>

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Amanda](http://www.amanda.org/)</sup>

Comment: with LuckBackup, I need to be able to send this to an FTP server, but when I try to specify the destination, it does not see my mount? When using rsync with destination ftp:// username:password@192.168.1.5/directory/ I get 'ssh: Could not resolve hostname ftp: Name or service not known